# Eigenvalues of the vectors of

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across the following problem:

"Let $\mathbf a\in\mathbf{R}^n$ be a ﬁxed $n$-component real, non-zero, vector. Let $A^+$ and $A^−$ be real $n\times n$ matrices with components:

$$(A^\pm)_{ij} = \delta_{ij} \pm a_ia_j $$

Obtain the eigenvalues of $A^\pm$ and describe the corresponding eigenvectors."

I've tried the general method for eigenvalues using the determinant, however, I got nowhere.
Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

Are the eigenvectors **a**, given that:

$$Aa=a+aa^Ta$$
$$Aa=a(I+a^Ta)$$

Hence the eigenvalues $(1+a^Ta)$

Also vectors orthogonal to **a** will be eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1.

Is this correct?

Comment: Write out $A^\pm v$ for $v\in \mathbb R^n$ in terms of $a$.

Comment: Hint, the matrices $A^\pm$ rewrite $A^\pm=I\pm\mathbf a\mathbf a^T$.

Comment: @V.Rossetto It's not $I$, it's $[\delta_{ij}]$

Comment: @Bilou06 Usually $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and $\delta_{ij}=0$ if $i\ne j$. Is your case different?

Comment: @V.Rossetto I haven't seen the notation for a while, but it reminds me something...

Comment: Hint using $A^+ - A^- = 2aa^T$, have a look to eigenvalues of $A^+$ that are orthogonal with $a$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{A}^{\pm } &=&\mathbf{U}\pm \mathbf{aa} \\
\mathbf{A}^{\pm }\cdot \mathbf{a} &=&\mathbf{a}\pm \mathbf{aa\cdot a}=(1\pm
\mathbf{a}^{2})\mathbf{a}
\end{eqnarray*}
so the eigenvalues are $(1\pm \mathbf{a}^{2})$.

Comment: What about vectors perpendicular to **a**? Are they not also eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes, you are right, they are eigenvectors at the eigenvalue 1